# TypeScript interface similar properties

Tags: typescript, interface

I am working on TS project and I have complicated structure of classes (Abstract Factory). The issue is that I have the interface that looks like:

```
export interface IProduct {
  customization: Customization;
  preparation: Preparation;

  make: () => void;

  setMilk?: (volume: number) => void;
  setWater?: (volume: number) => void;
  setSugar?: (volume: number) => void;
}
```

So, I have many similar setter properties (last 3) and it need to be more, but the template is the same. The question: is there some way to shorten them in one line? Something that looks like:

```
['set*': string]: (volume: number) => void;
```

(maybe some trick with index signature etc.)

Comment: You can use an actual index signature [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvP2W) which would allow for anything that begins with `set`.  If you need to constrain it to some union of key names you could do [this I guess](https://tsplay.dev/WolPew).  I'm happy to write either of these up as an answer if you mention which one works better for you.

Comment: Why have an interface at all if you are defining fields on the interface that will never be implemented?

Comment: @jcalz you`re wonderful, thank you

Comment: @YuriiHrecheniuk so which approach do you want?  Both?  I guess I can write up both.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to accept any possible key that starts with `"set"`, including things you didn't specify like `"setFlour"` or `"setRandomThing"` or `"settingSun"` or `"set$$1234Blah"`:

Before TypeScript 4.4 there was no way to do this with a specific object type.  Now, though, there is support for [template string pattern index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures).  An index signature is of the form `{[dummyKeyName: KeyType]: ValueType}` where `KeyType` represents the kind of keys to which you want the signature to apply. Traditionally you could only use `string` or `number` for `KeyType`.  TS4.4 enabled the use of *pattern template literal types* of the form `` `set${string}` ``, as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598), where `string` is a "pattern" or "placeholder" in a template literal type.

For your example, that means you can write this:

```
export interface IProduct {
  customization: Customization;
  preparation: Preparation;
  make: () => void;
  [k: `set${string}`]: (volume: number) => void
}
```

And test it out:

```
declare const p: IProduct;
p.setMilk(1);
p.setSugar(2);
p.setWater(3);
p.setFlour(4); //okay
```

---

On the other hand, if you only want to accept `"milk"` or `"water"` or `"sugar"`, or some other enumerated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of specific string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), you can do it instead by extending [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) with appropriate `K` and `V` types:

namespace ListOfKeys {
type SetKeys = 'milk' | 'water' | 'sugar';

```
export interface IProduct extends Record<
  `set${Capitalize<SetKeys>}`, (volume: number) => void
> {
  customization: Customization;
  preparation: Preparation;
  make: () => void;
}
```

And test it out:

```
declare const p: IProduct;
p.setMilk(1);
p.setSugar(2);
p.setWater(3);
p.setFlour(4); //error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbYALzjGBxGQG9k4AuZEdPAI2mQF8AoUSWRFAApQIABzhQSZCtWb1GLNl04g4eCJjFJkASRAATCAA8AysADmKsOmFVOnZMiMicUMMh7R4W7UJx70CG6U9g7ICFi4BMSk5PQY2PhEkuQA3CEOIsJiEjEg9EKi4skgaaHIeHAA1hD0ABQAlMgAvAB8yABuOMB6paEA2pX0AAaYEGAAJJTYUKBm7EMAunWdADZMNQxMrFCNrR1deiFKDgYIK+IoCOTYyCL0PlB+AWC9IgB0o2AAssArlbUARnqrw+Y2M6DM4lqACZgSF3p8AOokaC1ADMcIyoLAADEVjhrLUACzA5AAejJOEqcAAnnYlCo1Bp+MgADLAbAAeRgAGkIDTMLYHGAaSIUMYxnyBc1kAByAh-WXIAA+coA7iioErVbLMBDxLK0iEnC43B4+N5fP5Ao5DJB9IKAEoQK5QPQAHhGY0mqDgImAYDgKyIEHdErAUswLXmABpkLVVus5FtoLs2p1um1gmVwgkosU4hFEtEpL0Mlkirl8hWcqX0uUqhsGs10wdesdkKdzjYriAbncdFbniDPj8-oDMbdseDIVAYZOEWNkbx0QvsXiCXOSSlyWToI8oJx2EA)

Comment: again - u`r wonderful, thank you